# Is it necessary to run upgradesstables before upgrading from Cassandra 4.0.5 to 4.1.1?

Tags: cassandra

Do I need to run `nodetool <options> upgradesstables` if I am planning to upgrade Cassandra version from 4.0.5 to 4.1.1?

Comment: see point 6 of: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/89861/162995

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upgrading Cassandra from 1.1.0 to latest](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/89383/upgrading-cassandra-from-1-1-0-to-latest)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is always recommended to optionally perform `nodetool upgradesstable` while you're at the current version just to make sure all SSTables are conformant to the current binary version's format and then yes, strongly recommended to do it again post doing a binary version upgrade to a later version. More detailed steps are available in the answers by Luuk.

Answer (score 1):

The general recommendation is to run `nodetool upgradesstables` on each node **before** performing any upgrade. The main reasons are:

1. It is a good opportunity to catch any old SSTables that needs to be rewritten to the latest format.
2. If there are no SSTables to upgrade, it's a no-op anyway.

Strictly speaking, it is possible to upgrade from 4.0 to 4.1 without running `nodetool upgradesstables` because both Cassandra 4.0 and 4.1 [support reading older formats all the way back to `-ma-` (C* 3.0)](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-4.1/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/io/sstable/format/big/BigFormat.java#L125). However, you have nothing to lose by at least verifying that there are no old SSTables on disk. Cheers!